# Is it possible to have a html hyperlink with a verb (method/action) POST, PUT or DELETE?

Tags: hyperlink, restful-url, http-verbs

Is there any other verb than GET that we may send with a straight html hyperlink?

Do you know any document that specify why a html hyperlink only use the GET method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, links make GET requests.

They only make GET requests because it doesn't make sense for them to use any other standard verb. They can't POST because there is nothing to POST. They can't PUT for the same reason. They can't HEAD or OPTIONS because those verbs don't provide data useful to humans (other than developers doing debugging work). etc.